# Find the link in the text and convert it to the embed code

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm doing a study with Angular for news, announcement website.
I'm printing the content as `<div [innerHTML]='res.content'></div>`. But the contents have youtube links and they appear as text.

I am;
In the content of the 'div' element, I want to determine the links in youtube and convert them to 'embed code'.

An example res.content from Api;

```
"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>test yazıdır.</strong></p>\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n<b> </b>\r\n<h4>project description</h4>\r\nMaturity is required as young people will look to the volunteer (&amp;\r\nstaff in general) as a role model.\r\n<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>\r\n<h4>how to apply</h4>\r\nSend CV and covering letter to <strong>info@galwaysteinerschool.com</strong> and name of sending organisation where applicable\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n<strong>Son Başvuru Tarihi:</strong> 01/02/2019\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgUVUVY2e-I\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n<strong>EVS gönderici kuruluş listesi ve başvuru ile ilgili makalemize ulaşmak için <a href=\"http://www.example.com/agh-avrupa-gonullu-hizmeti-nedir-evs/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>Diğer AGH/EVS ilanlarına ulaşmak için <a href=\"http://www.example.com/category/evs-agh-firsatlari/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>Motivasyon Mektubu Nasıl Yazılır makalemizi okumak için <a title=\"Motivasyon Mektubu Nasıl Yazılır?\" href=\"http://www.example.com/motivasyon-mektubu-nasil-yazilir/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>Blog yazarımız Seher Can’ın Avrupa Gönüllü Hizmeti deneyimi makalesi için <a href=\"http://www.example.com/portekiz-avrupa-gonullu-hizmeti-deneyimi/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>Blog yazarımız Emre Gögebakan’ın Avrupa Gönüllü Hizmeti başvuru süreci makalesi için <a href=\"http://www.example.com/evs-arayan-genc/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>AGH/EVS mülakatı teknikleri makalemiz için <a href=\"http://www.example.com/agh-mulakati-ve-skype-gorusmesi/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>AGH EN ÇOK SORULAN SORULAR VE CEVAPLARI makalemiz için <a href=\"http://example.com/agh-en-cok-sorulan-sorular-ve-cevaplari/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n<strong>Başarılı Motivasyon Mektubu Teknikleri makalemiz için <a href=\"http://example.com/basarili-motivasyon-mektubu-teknikleri/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">tıklayınız.</a></strong>\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n\r\n<strong>Kaynak:</strong> <a href=\"https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/project/9729_en\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/project/9729_en</a>\r\n\r\n&nbsp;\r\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>Bu ilan Avrupa Birliği resmi sitesinden duyuru amaçlı kaynak gösterilerek Türkçe diline çevrilmiştir. İlan sorumluluğu example.com sitesinde değildir. Özgeçmiş ve motivasyon mektubu hazırlanması işlemlerinde ÜCRETSİZ olarak kurumumuz destek vermektedir. Kurumumuzun başvurunun olumlu veya olumsuz sonuçlanması konusunda herhangi bir taahhüdü ve etkisi yoktur.</strong></p>";
```

What kind of a method should I apply for this? and how can I?

> What I want to do exactly is find the youtube url inside the article and automatically translate it into the youtube embed code.

Thank you from now.

Comment: Take a look at creating a safeHtml pipe: https://medium.com/@AAlakkad/angular-2-display-html-without-sanitizing-filtering-17499024b079

Comment: Use DomSanitizer and then use BypassSecurityTrustHtml . But be careful before allowing external content to be loaded in your DOM

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't cover what I want to do. I have a youtube link as text in my current content. I want to find that link

'<iframe width="926" height="523" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sgUVUVY2e-I" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

I want to bring this to shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to get the video id from the youtube link. 
Then all you need is to add it to the youtube embeded link.

So if you use regex to find the video link from the following link:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgUVUVY2e-I\

it would return you with this: sgUVUVY2e-I

Then you can insert that into the embeded link like this:

- https://www.youtube.com/embed/sgUVUVY2e-I

There are a tone of tutorials on using regex to find information inside a text, then it is all up to you how you want to dislay it.